# Fill block at Amethyst Bud position

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m currently trying to make amethyst… *infectious.* What happens is that a budding block of amethyst grows a crystal, that then is replaced with another block of amethyst, like this:
[image: Stage 1]

[image: Stage 2]
*Note: this was done manually.*

This creates an endless cycle where amethyst gradually spreads all over the world.

*Note: because amethyst buds cannot grow into blocks, the infection would only infect open spaces. This is why I would want amethyst, in order to avoid extra work.*

---

How would I do this with commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a command block on repeat with the properties always active and unconditional. Set the tick delay to 1 tick. Set a ticking area on it to keep the command block from disabling. Put in this code:

```
/fill ~300 ~100 ~300 ~-300 ~-100 ~300 budding_amethyst replace small_amethyst_bud
```

This replaces all amethyst crystals with budding amethyst in a 300 block radius of you.

Comment: I needed to add the `blockdata:int` for the command to work. As well, the coordinates cover too much volume, command block throws an error. Adjusted the settings for successful execution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback!